# SharePoint 2010 Lib

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Доброго времени суток, Господа!
Есть задача: на сервере есть сайт на SharePoint 2010, в подкаталлогах которого имеются excel файлы. Организованы права доступа, я имею право добавлять и редактировать эти файлы через SharePoint. Мне необходимо написать клиента для загрузки и редактирования excel файлов. Нужна консольная версия приложения, так как код будет встроен в сервис. Подскажите как проще это реализовать, тащить SharePoint SDK или лучше обойтись другими средствами?

Comment: Чем не устраивает WebAppExcel?

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте!
Для загрузки файлов в вашем случае я бы использовал CSOM (Client server object model), примеры можно посмотреть по [ссылке](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/FP179912.aspx)
Так же можно использовать SharePoint REST API.